# Сериализация XML файла из Text Asset Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможна ли сериализация и десериализация xml файла из Text Asset'a?
Сейчас это выполняется подобным образом, но при билде на iOS, xml отказывается работать. Я знаю, что проблема скорее всего связана с путями, если кто подскажет фикс этой проблемы благодарен.

Реализация:

```cs
        public void Save()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StarsData));
            using(var stream = new FileStream(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/XML/StarsData.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
            }
        }

        public static StarsData Load()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StarsData));
            using(var stream = new FileStream(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/XML/StarsData.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as StarsData;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Что значит "отказывается работать"? Исключение?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Вероятно, но т.к. я делаю тестовый билд через iOS bulder (прога из ассет стора), он не показывает ексепшены. Но в редакторе все работает безупречно.

Comment: Не пользовался iOS builder'ом, однако на странице ассета заявлена поддержка вывода всех логов приложения, развернутого на телефоне. Вам следует узнать через этот функционал конкретную ошибку, не факт, что проблема именно в путях ;)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я делал десериализацию через текст ассет и на телефоне она работала хорошо, когда дело дошло до сериализации, я не смог ее сделать из текст ассета. Сейчас выдумываю велосипеды с Application.persistentDataPath

Comment: Почему вы не хотите просто и быстро узнать конкретную ошибку через логи? Streaming assets - readonly папка, сериализовать в новый или даже существующий файл не выйдет. `persistentDataPath` сработает, но тут нужно быть аккуратнее, чтобы не превратить папку в "помойку".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил таким образом:

```cs
  public void Save()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StarsData));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/StarsData.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
            }
        }

        public static StarsData Load()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StarsData));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/StarsData.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as StarsData;
            }
        }

        public static void CheckForExists(TextAsset textAsset)
        {
            var path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/StarsData.xml";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Dispose();
            }
            
            File.WriteAllText(path, textAsset.text);
        }
```

И в Awake сцены просто вызываю данный метод. На обоих платформах работает привосходно.